# Uploading file either using httpReguest or Webrequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, post, webrequest

I would like to upload a csv file to census geocoding website and get a csv file back but I kept getting webexception errors or get stuck on the request no matter how I tweak the code. If you have any suggestion or have dealt with this kind of problem, please share your two cents. When it comes to composing the string params/concatenating them, I am not an expert 
Here is my mess

```
namespace getPostgeocode
{
    class Program
    {
           /*private static string geos = "geographies";
           private static string addresses = "addressbatch";
            private static string benchmark = "Public_AR_Current";
            private static string vintage = "Current_Current";
            private static string returntype = "locations";
            private static string returntype = "locations";*/



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            //StringBuilder paramURI = new StringBuilder();
            // Create a request instance.  
            // paramURI.AppendFormat(format: @"{0}?benchmark={1}&vintage={2}&returntype={3}"
            //, arg0: benchmark, arg1: vintage, arg2: returntype);


            string baseURI = "http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/";
            var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(baseURI);
            var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
            query["benchmark"] = "Public_AR_Current";
            query["vintage"] = "Current_Current";
            query["returntype"] = "locations";
            query["geo"] = "geographies";
            query["addressbatch"] = "addressbatch";
            uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
            baseURI = uriBuilder.ToString();

            WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create(baseURI);
            myRequest.Method = "POST";
            string boundary = "----------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
            myRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
            //myRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            myRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            Console.WriteLine(baseURI);
            Console.ReadLine();

            WebResponse geoResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = geoResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader geoReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string addString = geoReader.ReadToEnd();

            dataStream.Close();
            geoResponse.Close();


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the text of the exception message? Which line throws it? When your program hangs, does it hang permanently or eventually time out?

Comment: Isn't this API served over `https` these days?

Comment: It eventually times out. It doesn't matter if it's http or https

Comment: @O.Jones I have not kept all errors problems but now I am completely blocked from the site even after using https and another code with httpRequest

Comment: 148.129.75.136 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Comment: Hmmm.  Did they block you?  Sometimes API owners do things like that.

Comment: @O. Jones I did not do anything except trying to upload a csv file. I do not know exactly why my address has been flagged. I will try it from home and see how it goes. Arghhh. Thank you